# How do I fill a list in python with elements from a specific set?

Tags: python, list, random, set, combinations

If I have a set of integers which denote the values that a list element can take and a python list of a given length.

I want to fill the list with all possible combinations.

**example**

> list `length=3` and the `my_set ={1,-1}`

**Possible combinations**

```
[1,1,1],[1,1,-1],[1,-1,1],[1,-1,-1],
[-1,1,1],[-1,1,-1],[-1,-1,1],[-1,-1,-1]
```

I tried approaching with random.sample method from random class
but it doesn't help. I did:

```
my_set=[1,-1]
from random import sample as sm
print sm(my_set,1)    #Outputs: -1,-1,1,1 and so on..(random)
print sm(my_set,length_I_require)        #Outputs**:Error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what `itertools.product` is for :

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product({1,-1},repeat=3))
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, -1), (1, -1, 1), (1, -1, -1), (-1, 1, 1), (-1, 1, -1), (-1, -1, 1), (-1, -1, -1)]
>>>
```

And if you want the result as list you can use `map` to convert the iterator of tuples to list if list (in python3 it returns an iterator which as a more efficient way you can use a list comprehension ):

```
>>> map(list,product({1,-1},repeat=3))
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, -1], [1, -1, 1], [1, -1, -1], [-1, 1, 1], [-1, 1, -1], [-1, -1, 1], [-1, -1, -1]]
```

In python3 :

```
>>> [list(pro) for pro in product({1,-1},repeat=3)]
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, -1], [1, -1, 1], [1, -1, -1], [-1, 1, 1], [-1, 1, -1], [-1, -1, 1], [-1, -1, -1]]
>>>
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`itertools.product()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import product

result = [list(combo) for combo in product(my_set, repeat=length)]
```

The `list()` call is optional; if tuples instead of lists are fine to, then `result = list(product(my_set, repeat=length))` suffices.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> length = 3 
>>> my_set = {1, -1}
>>> list(product(my_set, repeat=length))
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, -1), (1, -1, 1), (1, -1, -1), (-1, 1, 1), (-1, 1, -1), (-1, -1, 1), (-1, -1, -1)]
>>> [list(combo) for combo in product(my_set, repeat=length)]
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, -1], [1, -1, 1], [1, -1, -1], [-1, 1, 1], [-1, 1, -1], [-1, -1, 1], [-1, -1, -1]]
```

`random.sample()` gives you a random subset of the given input sequence; it doesn't produce all possible combinations of values.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst_length = 3
my_set = {1,-1}
result = [[x] for x in my_set]
for i in range(1,lst_length):
    temp = []
    for candidate in my_set:
        for item in result:
            new_item = [candidate]
            new_item += item
            temp.append(new_item)
    result = temp
print result
```

If the list length is 1, the result is a list whose elements equal to the set. Every time the list length increases one, the result can be gotten by append each element of the set to the resulted list.